# Current year data from table as per Month Record

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i have this query which is fine working....

```
 $result        =   mysql_query(SELECT Month(ord_aff_date) AS saleMonth, ROUND(SUM(ord_aff_amount),0) AS Total 
                FROM order_affiliate_details 
                WHERE aff_id='12' AND YEAR(ord_aff_date)=YEAR(CURDATE())
                GROUP BY Month(ord_aff_date) ORDER BY Month(ord_aff_date)");

while($datas    =   mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $months[]=$datas['saleMonth'];
    $value[]=   $datas['Total'];
}

print_r($months); exit;
```

And the result as given below, and not all months, shows... which is right..

```
 Result => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 )
```

Now i want to get a array of values, like this one.

```
Array(['January', 437], ['February', 322], ['March', 233], ['April', 110], ['May', 34], ['June', 20], ['July', 19], ['August', 110], ['September', 34], ['November', 20], ['December', 19],);
```

as js array.. . but now i am stuck how to do that.... can any one help me....??

**Solution:**

```
// As i want to get these data as a json encoded and also in another array, 
// but with out square brackets at the end.. so now i find the solution which 
// is fit in as js library want...

$final = array_combine($arr_monthName,$values);
    $allMonths = array();
    $i=0;
    foreach($final as $k=>$v)
    {   
        $allMonths[$i]=array($k,$v);
        $i++;
    } 

    // then do json_encode
    $json = json_encode($allMonths);
    $json = preg_replace('/^\[|\]$/', '', $json);

 // answer return as....
 => ['January', 437], ['February', 322], ['March', 233], ['April', 110], ['May', 34]

 // which then i pass to a js array.... simply.
 var arrayData = new Array(<?=$json?>);

 // many many thanks to diEcho, which help me to get this... thanks.
```

Comment: currently u r getting output like this `array(0=>array('saleMonth'=>'January','total=>437), 1=>array('saleMonth'=>'February','total=>322) ... )`  right??

Comment: NO, this not like this.... at only show's number as per month not name,,, and payment to each month....  As i want to achieve this like your query and then to json to give to javascript variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand your problem then  i think currently u r getting output like this

```
$output = array(0=>array('saleMonth'=>'January','total=>437),
                1=>array('saleMonth'=>'February','total=>322). ... )
```

### update

```
// first create an array having key as month name and value as total
// suppose we have below array

$monthArray = array( 0=>2, 1 =>3, 2=> 4, 3=>5 );
$valueArray = array( 0=>437,1=>322, 2=>233,4=>458);
function intToMonth($monthNumber)
{
    $strTime=mktime(1,1,1,$monthNumber,1,date("Y"));
    return date("F",$strTime);  
}
$arr_monthName= array_map('intToMonth',$monthArray);    
$final = array_combine($arr_monthName,$valueArray);
//final array would be 

 Array
(
    [February] => 437
    [March] => 322
    [April] => 233
    [May] => 458
)
// then do json_encode
json_encode($final);
//output would be in below format, Associative array always output as object:
{"February":437,"March":322,"April":233,"May":458}
```

### more update

to get the output as array of array, try

```
$new = array();
$i=0;
foreach($final as $k=>$v)
{   
    $new[$i]=array($k,$v);
    $i++;
}
json_encode($new);
//output would be in below format , array of array
[["February",437],["March",322],["April",233],["May",458]]
```

**[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)**

Comment: will u update your question with  what exactly the output is??

Comment: I have update my question please see it... and give upward the marks..plz.

Comment: @diEcho, you had done fantastically, its awsome...... totally what i want... but how you understand my problem and give this result while other are miss understand it.....

Comment: its all right, but can not work with js library which required array of like in my question last array of js type.... can we get json from php array to like that one... and once again thanks...

Comment: now whatever u want to do, you can, `[`is array and `{` is object notation in **JSON**

Comment: **Associative array always output as object**  read here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @ime please check my more update section :) at most you can do this.

Comment: @ime you can use `json_decode` instead of `new Array(<?=$json?>);`. anyway happy to see that you got your own skill :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to output a JS array.